# javascript exceptions, not caught by debugger after installing typescript 1.4 with VS 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

Javascript exceptions, syntax errors  not caught by debugger after installing typescript 1.4 with VS 2013.

An example of code ("whaever" doesn't exist - it's a fake object and function):

```
whatever.show("something");
```

Debugging in .ts files works fine, this code sits in a .js file unrelated to typescript. It should get caught by the VS debugger when trying to execute it. Instead, it stops executing JS code from the current file and skips everything after the code above without throwing any exceptions.

I've tried uninstalling, repairing, reinstalling typescript - and also uninstalled/reinstalled VS2013.

Anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: Solution - thanks to Gent, it became apparent that the .js.map file wasn't being re-generated, because of inccorrect settings in the project file. In this case, I set <TypeScriptSourceMap>False</TypeScriptSourceMap> to True, and this did the trick. The map file was re-generated, and VS now catches JS errors again.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update which version of TypeScript the project is using.  It is likely set to 1.0, you should set it to 1.4 or whatever version of the compiler you have installed.  It might be confusing the tooling or just failing to build entirely.

In your project file:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

Another potential issue would be if your map files are not set to be output during compilation:

```
<TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
```

Comment: if you delete the map file does it get regenerated?

Comment: not sure what it is - which extension should I be looking for?

Comment: map files get generated to map between the JS and TS for debugging/readability.  If you are missing these files or they are not being generated properly I would guess that is whats causing your trouble.  Each of the files should be a tripple, .js .ts and .js.map

Comment: Nice catch, the file indeed does not get re-generated.

Comment: If you run the tsc from command line does it get regenerated?  If so I would guess the path to the TypeScript build targets changed but the project files still looks in the old place, and when it doesnt exists gets ignored

Comment: Right now it is giving me a number of syntax errors with string array declerations - which I assume VS should inform me when building the project. In the project file I have the following, but these seem to be correct paths:   <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="js\ptNoteV5.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\typings\jquery\jquery.d.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: @MichelHuy so just for ease of testing lets just have on include that does **\*.ts which will pull in all ts files into the compilation.

Comment: <TypeScriptCompile Include="js\\*.ts" /> does get the solution to compile without errors (***.ts does not) but the map file does not get re-generated.

Comment: <TypeScriptCompile Include="**\\*.ts" /> should pull in all typescript files recursively.  I was at a dinner counter and didn't notice the "\" got escaped

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing in the right direction. While changing the include path didn't cause to re-generate the map file, I noticed this entry: <TypeScriptSourceMap>False</TypeScriptSourceMap>, which I set to True and this solved all the probs.

Comment: I amended the answer to include the solution, so the next folks to run into this will have the info.